# How to get random color using javascript (only dark colors)?

Tags: javascript

I need a function which returns only dark colors.

I am able to get random colors using below code. But how to limit this to fetch only dark colors.

```js
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

If not how can I define some pool of colors in an array and fetch from that ?

Comment: I not sure if this would work for you..but would you want to consider using SASS? And then use the darken function
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20114631/9624675

Answer (score 3):

In my mind the more easy is to use HSL color system ( Hue, Saturation, Light )

sample code:

```js
const mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv')

document.querySelector('button').onclick=_=>
  {
  let colorH = Math.floor(Math.random() *359)
    , colorS = Math.floor(Math.random() *40) +60
    , colorL = Math.floor(Math.random() *15) +7  // dark colors to adjust
    ;
  mydiv.style.setProperty('--colorBG', `hsl(${colorH}, ${colorS}%, ${colorL}%)`)
  }
```

```css
#mydiv {
  --colorBG: hsl(0, 100%, 15%);  /* 0..359 */
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color: var(--colorBG);
  }
* {margin: 1em;}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"> </div>

<button>Random color</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The lower the lvl, the darker. 256 is full range.

```js
lvl = 128;
color = Math.floor(Math.random()*lvl)<<16 | Math.floor(Math.random()*lvl)<<8 | Math.floor(Math.random()*lvl);
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.backgroundColor = '#' + color.toString(16).padStart(6, "0");
```

```css
div { height: 100px; width:100%; }
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Colors are basically RGB (red, green, blue) mixtures with R, G, and B each having a dark-to-light value of 0-255. 0 is the darkest version of that color (meaning actually completely black), and 255 is the lightest (white).

If you want to get a "dark" color, stay on the lower half of the 0-255 spectrum and only pick colors from 0 through 127. Then, if you  want your colors to be hex values, you can convert that 0-127 number to hex by saying `.toString(16)`. That will convert it to a base 16 value, which is hex. You'll do this **3 times in a row**, once for R, once for G, and once for B.

You're going to want to make sure each of these base 16 0-127 values has a leading 0 if needed so we don't end up with some malformed 5 character hex color string. A short way to do this is just to add a `"0"` to the front no matter what and then [slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) the *last* two characters out of the string, leaving the `"0"` out if it's unneeded.

Picking from a pool doesn't really even need an explanation.

```js
document.getElementById("dark").style.background = "#" + ("0" + rando(127).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("0" + rando(127).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("0" + rando(127).toString(16)).slice(-2);
document.getElementById("darkFromPool").style.background = rando(["black", "darkgreen", "darkred"]).value;
```

```css
div { height: 50px; margin: 10px 0px 30px 0px; border-radius: 4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>

Random dark: <div id="dark"></div>
Random dark from pool: <div id="darkFromPool"></div>
```

This code uses [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to simplify the randomness and make it more readable. So, if you want to use this code, just make sure this is in the head tag of your HTML document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Code snippet in HTML,CSS and Javascript shows how to generate random colours

```js
const setBg = () => {
  const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
  color.textContent = "#" + randomColor;
}

genNew.addEventListener("click", setBg);
setBg();
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-family: system-ui;
}
h1 {
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <button id="genNew">Generate New Random Color</button>
  <span id="color"></span>
</h1>
```